# SQL query not creating my columns?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-database

I am trying to create a fitness app where the database saves a username and password.
then enters their details that saves to a second table. This is my dbHelper.

The error im getting is that my "Username Column does not exist"
But when i go and look at my tables using db browser for sqlite
it shows my tables created and data in my tables

UPDATE : I created 1 table to store all my data and now its not picking up still im getting "not set" from my display method

updated table

```
// Register table
public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
public static final String COL_2 = "Username";
public static final String COL_3 = "Password";
public static final String COL_4 = "Weight";
public static final String COL_5 = "Height";
public static final String COL_6 = "TargetWeight";
public static final String COL_7 = "TargetSteps";
```

display method

```
 public String DisplayData(String username,String column)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ TABLE_NAME +" WHERE Username =?",new String[]{username});
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        return cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column));
    }else{
        return "Not set";
    }
}
```

Usage

```
public void setData() {
    db = new dbHelper(this);

    try {
        userWeight.setText(db.DisplayData(Username, dbHelper.COL_4));
        userHeight.setText(db.DisplayData(Username, dbHelper.COL_5));
        userTargetWeight.setText(db.DisplayData(Username, dbHelper.COL_6));
        userTargetSteps.setText(db.DisplayData(Username, dbHelper.COL_7));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: what you have passed in DisplayData() ? Show your Error log

Comment: If you have changed the Database structure then try to uninstall the previous build and and build again . Apart from that i suggest  to  make use of  [Android-Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room).

Comment: For my error log , like logcat?

Comment: I have not changed my database structure at all. Il try android -room

Comment: What im trying to do is for the display method to get the username and then display the data that user entered . I used Username = admin to see why my return was "Not set" . I used a session to hold the username. and then Got the error/throw "column Weight does not exist" else previously it was WHERE Username = ?, new String[]{Username});

Comment: After your latest edit, it seems like you're mixing up `TABLE_NAME` and `TABLE_NAME1` - consider naming your table name constants in more descriptive way so that it's easier for you to keep track which one you should be using in code.

Comment: Okay thanks got it, yeah i did switch them around after correcting it . i was still getting an error where it cant find the column

Answer (score 0):

`TABLE_NAME1` has no `Username` column. update your method as follow

```
public String DisplayData(String username, String column) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ TABLE_NAME +" WHERE " + column + " = ? ", new String[]{username});
    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()){
        return cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column));
    } else {
        return "Not set";
    }
}
```

and use it like this

```
.DisplayData("admin", "Username");
```

Comment: may be think about clearing your app's data too before restesting

Comment: How can i do this? and i just tested now and i corrected the tables and tried what you are suggesting but still getting "Weight column does not exist"

Comment: to clear data use adb with this command `adb shell pm clear packageName` or from the device *Settings->apps-> your applicatioon->clear data*.. the weight column is in TABLE_NAME1, when are you querying this table?

Comment: if you're using the same method `DisplayData` to query different tables you will have to change the method otherwise it won't work

Comment: thank you , and what im trying to do is display the data from "admin"  which the data is displayed in another table.  so how do i then tell it that i want this users details displayed. so when the user registered Username and password are kept in table_name and when they enter their details its kept in table_name1. How do i then "tell" my app that this user has these details

Comment: based on your update.. you have a serious issue with your database.. TABLE_NAME and TABLE_NAME1 are not the same and are not connected.. you need to have the user id in TABLE_NAME1.. rework your database model

Comment: The easiest solution for you is to have only one table.. then you'll have the information you need

Answer (score 0):

Your issue, assuming that value of the 2nd argument of the `Displaydata` method is **Username** is that you are querying TABLE_NAME1 (**profile_data**) table, which doesn't have a column named **Username**.

Instead I believe you want to be querying the TABLE_NAME (**register_table** table) table so change :-

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ TABLE_NAME1 +" WHERE Username = 'admin' ",null);
```

to :-

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ TABLE_NAME +" WHERE Username = 'admin' ",null);
```

### Additional re comment :-

> Im not longer getting an error but its still not displaying the
>   correcting infomation . Im getting "Not set " from my displayData
>   method. from my if ELSE

Assuming that you have added data and getting the above then it is likely that Username does not equate to a row in the table. Try using the following version of `DisplayData` to debug :-

```
// Note changed to use recommended convenience query method
// Note closes cursor thus uses intermediate variable (rv) to allow close
public String DisplayData(String username,String column)
{
    String rv = "Not set";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    //Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ TABLE_NAME +" WHERE Username =?",new String[]{username}); //<<<<< replaced
    String whereclause = COL_2 + "=?";
    String[] whereargs = new String[]{username};
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME,null,whereclause,whereargs,null,null,null);
    //<<<<<<<<<< FOLLOWING CODE ADDED TO LOG DEBUG INFO >>>>>>>>>>
    Log.d("DISPLAYDATAINFO","Display was called with Username as:- " +
            username +
            " for Column:- " +
            column +
            ". The Cursor contains " +
            String.valueOf(cursor.getCount()) +
            " ."
    );
    //<<<<<<<<<< END OF ADDED DEBUG CODE >>>>>>>>>>
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        rv =  cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column));
    }
    cursor.close(); //<<<< SHOULD ALWAYS CLOSE CURSOR WHEN DONE WITH IT
    return rv;
}
```

This should produce output in the log along the lines of :-

```
05-18 23:08:25.429 2926-2926/fitness.fitness D/DISPLAYDATAINFO: Display was called with Username as:- Fred for Column:- Weight. The Cursor contains 5 .
    Display was called with Username as:- Fred for Column:- Height. The Cursor contains 5 .
    Display was called with Username as:- Fred for Column:- TargetWeight. The Cursor contains 5 .
    Display was called with Username as:- Fred for Column:- TargetSteps. The Cursor contains 5 .
```

- Note 5 because when testing new data is inserted each run so the above indicates the 5th run.

**Or in the case of nothing being found (your current issue) something like** :-

```
05-18 23:11:40.342 2926-2926/fitness.fitness D/DISPLAYDATAINFO: Display was called with Username as:- Tom for Column:- Weight. The Cursor contains 0 .
    Display was called with Username as:- Tom for Column:- Height. The Cursor contains 0 .
    Display was called with Username as:- Tom for Column:- TargetWeight. The Cursor contains 0 .
    Display was called with Username as:- Tom for Column:- TargetSteps. The Cursor contains 0 .
```

- i.e. Cursor contains 0 = no rows exist for the given username (Tom in this case).
- Check if the Username is as expected (note case of letters must match, in the above a row for tom exists but not for Tom hence 0 count for the cursor).
- Column retrieval appears to be correct, However, still check that the columns in the output are as expected (can't see that they would not be).

Comment: Yes i picked up on that mistake and changed it. Now my error has changed to "column Username does not exist"

Comment: If that error is with the modified table (register_table) (with columns added) then try deleting the App's data or uninstalling the App and then rerunning the App. The **`onCreate` method is only invoked when the database is first created**. Note, any data in the database will be lost. If this is an issue then you need to say so and include the full code for the database helper class *(basically an `ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN column_definition for the column to be added` could be used)*

Comment: Thank you . no its no problem if i delete the data, il try that now ! With the updated version . Im not longer getting an error but its still not displaying the correcting infomation . Im getting "Not set  " from my displayData method. from my if ELSE

Comment: have you added any data? If so are you sure it's adding(inserting) the data.  Perhaps add a temporary method that gets all data and logs cursor.getCount(). Perhaps edit your question to include how you are adding data.

Comment: Thanks so much il give this a shot tonight!